# Python Hex File Write

Tags: python, file, binary, hex

I have a list that looks like this:

```
['\x12', '\x13', '\x05', ... , '\xF2']
```

and I'm trying to write it to a file in binary form like this:

```
00010010
00010011
00000101
11110010
```

This is what I'm doing now:

```
for dataLine in readData:
    print int(binascii.hexlify(dataLine), 16)
```

And then converting to 8 bit binary like so:

```
def dobin(n):
    digs = []

    while n > 0:
        digs.append(str(n % 2))
        n /= 2

    for x in range(len(digs), 8):
        digs.append('0')

    digs.reverse()
    return ''.join(digs)
```

Is there an easy way to convert these to binary or a better way all together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version that should work on Python 2.6 (or higher):

```
>>> data = ['\x12', '\x13', '\x05', '\xF2']
>>> [bin(ord(c))[2:].zfill(8) for c in data]                                                                                                                 
['00010010', '00010011', '00000101', '11110010']
```

So to write this to a file, I would probably do something like this:

```
f = open('some_file', 'w')
f.write('\n'.join(bin(ord(c))[2:].zfill(8) for c in data))
f.close()
```

**Edit:** Didn't realize that `bin()` was not available on Python 2.5, you can define the following `bin()` function to get this to work:

```
def bin(i):
    s = []
    prefix = '0b' if i >= 0 else '-0b'
    if i < 0: i = -i
    while i:
        s.append('1' if i & 1 else '0')
        i = i >> 1
    return prefix + (''.join(reversed(s)) if s else '0')
```

Comment: I don't believe bin is available in 2.5 ... I'm getting a name not defined error

Comment: As [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin) say: "New in version 2.6." But since the OP didn't specify 2.5 as a requirement, it's probably easier to just change the answer, so I'll do that.

Comment: I could've swore I mentioned that- my mistake. Thanks for the reply!